# Is it possible to track keystrokes in a third party app/game?

Tags: python, winapi

Unable to track keystrokes in the game

I tried to do with keyboard win32api.GetKeyState in python but when i open the game nothing works. Maybe you need to somehow switch the focus to the application? I'm still new to this, if possible, tell me what needs to be studied.

Comment: `GetKeyState()` only works on the local keyboard state of the calling thread, which is updated only when the thread processes keyboard messages dispatched to it. Use `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()` to receive notifications of actual keyboard events before they are dispatched to the active window.

Comment: [Pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput) would probably do the job.